# Angular $q promise Unit testing using Mocha, Chai, Sinon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to get my simple angualr $q promise unit test to work. But I've been having problems getting it to work. 
Here's my angular file.

```
app.controller('theCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q) {
    $scope.addOne = function(num) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        if(angular.isNumber(num)) {
            q.resolve(num+1);
        } else {
            q.reject('NaN');
        }
        return q.promise;
    }

    $scope.myVal = 0;
    $scope.promise = $scope.addOne($scope.myVal);

    // $scope.promise.then(function(v) {$scope.myVal = v }, function(err) {$scope.myVal = err});

}]);
```

I'm using Mocha, Chai and sinon for the unit testing. 
Here's my test file.

```
describe("Contacts App", function() {
   describe("the contact service", function(){
       var $scope, theCtrl, $q;

       beforeEach(module('Contacts'));

       beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
           var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
           var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
           $scope = $rootScope.$new();
           theCtrl = $controller('theCtrl', {$scope: $scope} );
           $q = $injector.get('$q');     

       }));

       it('should have a properly working promise', function() {
           // Any answers?
       });
    });
});
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks, Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First proposition**

You can use mocha's callback function to test [asynchronous code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) along with the angular $timeout.flush()

```
it('should have a properly working promise', function(done) {
   expect($scope.promise).to.be.defined;
   $scope.promise.then(function() {
       done();
   });
   $timeout.flush();
});
```

**Second proposition** (recommended by Mocha)

You can use https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised and return a promise. Your code should look as below

```
it('should increment the input if number given', function() {
   return $scope.addOne(1).should.eventually.equal(2);
});
```