# Angularjs Mocha test $q promises without $rootScope.$apply

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, angular-promise, chai, karma-mocha

I have this service:

```
    angular.module('domeeApp')
        .factory('streamWidget', streamWidgetFactory);

    function streamWidgetFactory($q) {
        return {
            loadContent: function() { 
                return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                    resolve('test');
                }) 
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm testing it with karma/mocha/chai:

```
describe('streamWidget', function() {
    beforeEach(module('domeeApp'));
    var streamWidget;
    var $timeout;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$timeout_, _streamWidget_) {
        streamWidget = _streamWidget_;
        $timeout = _$timeout_;
    }));


    it('should load new content', function(done) {        
        streamWidget.loadContent()
        .then(function(res) {
            expect(res).to.equal('test');
            done();
        })
        .catch(function(){})
        $timeout.flush();
    });    
});
```

Since $q promises doesn't work well with mocha i'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35487547/3142367), which says to add `$timeout.flush()` to force the `.then` method of the promise to be executed.

The problem is, after calling .flush(), all my app wakes up and i start to get this errors from angular-mocks:

`Error: Unexpected request: GET /partials/page/view/index`.

I know about $httpBackend, but it would be **insane** to mock ALL the requests my app is making on startup.

**Is there a way to make `$q` promises work with mocha without calling `$timeout.flush()` or `$rootScope.$apply()`?**

Comment: The subject of the question is Chai, not Mocha. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/37374041/3731501

Comment: The subject of the question is the $q service and how i can force $q promises to be resolved without using apply/flush. Chai as nothing to do with it, since i'm not using chai-as-promised. At least, this is how i see the situation, if you don't agree, try to explain it better.

Comment: It is Chai that does assertions, not Mocha. Well, you may consider using chai-as-promised then, it is the way how $q promise assertions can be done without calling `$apply()` or `$digest()` after `then`.

Comment: I tried with chai-as-promised, but with the same result. If you can show me a working solution with it, i'll accept your answer.

Comment: Yes, `chai-as-promised` requires some extra setup, as the link above suggests. Fortunately it has got `transferPromiseness` hook to provide the desired behaviour for asserted promise (i.e. run a digest to execute the whole promise chain).

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37374041/3731501), `chai-as-promised` can be used to assert `$q` promises.
With this setup

```
chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = function (assertion, promise) {
  assertion.then = promise.then.bind(promise);

  if (!('$$state' in promise))
    return;

  inject(function ($rootScope) {
    if (!$rootScope.$$phase)
      $rootScope.$digest();
  });
};
```

digest cycles will be triggered automatically on promise assertions, executing the whole promise chain.

In this case the spec

```
it('...', () => {
  ...
  expect(...).to.eventually...;
  expect(...).to.eventually...;
  $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

can omit `$digest()` call and become

```
it('...', () => {
  ...
  expect(...).to.eventually...;
  expect(...).to.eventually...;
});
```

Notice that `$q` promises are synchronous, they shouldn't be returned from Mocha spec or call `done` callback.

Comment: I tried your solution, but the result is the same. When i call `$rootScope.$digest()`, be it in `chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness`  or wherever else, i start to get the same errors about unexpected requests. In fact, what i'm asking from beginning is how to do this test WITHOUT using $digest/$apply/$flush. At this point i guess there is no solution.

Comment: It seems that you mix the things up. These all are separate concerns. `$digest()` isn't a panacea. You NEED to trigger `$digest()` to execute $q promises (this is what the answer covers). You NEED to call `flush()` to execute $timeout timeouts. You NEED to mock $httpBackend requests in unit tests. There's no need to mock them all - only the requests that are made by tested unit. This is how Angular testing works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative strategy that we use because we *never* actually need `$httpBackend`, but it sometimes (randomly) fails making requests for templates used by directives (even though those templates are available in `$templateCache`):

```
beforeEach(function() {
  module('app', function($provide) {
    // This is using jasmine, but the idea is the same with mocha.
    // Basically just replace $httpBackend with a function that does nothing.
    $provide.constant('$httpBackend', jasmine.createSpy('$httpBackend'));
  });
});
```

Of course, if you actually *use* `$httpBackend` in other cases, then this won't work, as you'll need it to mock response objects.